# How to get Server Name and Server Port from Liferay velocity template?

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-velocity

In jsp page we can get Server Name and Server Port by using 
    request.getServerName() and request.getServerPort().`

As we can't get HttpServletRequest from Liferay velocity template, Is there any other way to 
get both  Server Name and Server Port ? Please answer with a small code snippet..

Comment: When you are saying Velocity template, are talking about a theme template or a web content display template or a layout-template ?
I'd understant if my question seem cryptic to you, if so, tell my I'll try to make myself clearer and explain more.

Comment: portal-normal.vm file available in thame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Liferay sources you can find `com.liferay.portal.velocity.VelocityVariablesImpl`.

This class is placed under `portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/velocity/VelocityVariablesImpl.java`.

If you check all entries to velocity context (lines like `velocityContext.put(String key, Object value)`) and specially the ones in the `insertVariables` method, you'll see that this exposes you httpServletRequest under the name `"request"`.

Therefore, in your template you access your request object as any other velocity context object with the key `$request`.

This object will, then, be usable with all it's methods and properties (if public).

So just do

```
$request.getServerName()
```

and

```
$request.getServerPort()
```

Furthermore, if you want to set a velocity variable to one of those, just do as follows

```
#set ($my_amazing_variable = $request.getServerPort())
```

You'll then be able to use `$my_amazing_variable` as any regular velocity litteral.

Hope this helps.

---

NOTA BENE !

Note that you do not have access to the exact same set of variables and macros under all types of velocity templates in Liferay.
There are different sets for

- theme templates
- layout templates
- web-content templates

Comment: No problem, it has made me suffer more than enough in a remote (and revolved) past so I don't want anybody else to endure the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have created my URL with below code for Login Pop up.Thanks Ar3s.

```
#set($protocol = "http://")
#set($host = "$request.getServerName()")
#set($port = "$request.getServerPort()")
#set($column = ":" )
#set($url = "/c/portal/login?p_l_id=10858" )
#set($hrefurl = "$protocol$host$column$port$url")


<a class="sign-in" data-redirect="false" href="$hrefurl" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1420097083820_231" role="menuitem" title=""> <span id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1420097083820_865" class="nav-item-label"> Sign In </span> </a>
```